# Executable Scriptspython.EXE not found for pre-commit (lose slashes)

Tags: python, windows, git, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

We created a pre-commit hook for our project. But when we ran that pre-commit on Windows, we got an error:

```
Check copyright notices...................................................................Failed
- hook id: check-copyright
- exit code: 1

Executable `C:Userstore.cachepre-commitrepoq2jv0lxhpy_env-python3.9Scriptspython.EXE` not found
```

So, pre-commit lose slashes for Windows machine. How to fix it? In pre-commit script we have `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang, could it be a problem with that?
For Unix-systems everything is ok

.pre-commit-config.yaml

```
- repo: https://github.com/espressif/check-copyright/
  rev: v1.0.0
  hooks:
    - id: check-copyright
      args: ['--ignore', 'tools/ci/check_copyright_ignore.txt', '--config', 'tools/ci/check_copyright_config.yaml']
```

.pre-commit-hooks.yaml:

```
- id: check-copyright
  name: Check copyright notices
  entry: check_copyright.py --verbose --replace
  language: python
  files: \.(py|c|h|cpp|hpp|ld|s|S)$
  require_serial: true
```

Full repository: https://github.com/espressif/check-copyright

Comment: show your configuration?

Comment: @AnthonySottile My colleague said that he used Windows 10 and Python 3.8.7, MS Terminal for developping.

Comment: no, show your `pre-commit` configuration -- otherwise we're guessing at your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the hook you are using is packaged poorly -- it doesn't properly support windows installations

their usage of `scripts` generates a file in the bin directory with a (bogus) shebang:

```
C:\Users\Anthony\workspace\check-copyright>head -1 venv\Scripts\check_copyright.py
#!C:\Users\Anthony\workspace\check-copyright\venv\Scripts\python.exe
```

the supported way to make platform-agnostic entrypoints is to utilize `console_scripts`:

the easiest fix is to submit a pull request which adjusts their usage of `scripts` to instead utilize `console_scripts`:

```
diff --git a/.pre-commit-hooks.yaml b/.pre-commit-hooks.yaml
index dd2ebf1..9ed932b 100644
--- a/.pre-commit-hooks.yaml
+++ b/.pre-commit-hooks.yaml
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 - id: check-copyright
   name: Check copyright notices
-  entry: check_copyright.py --verbose --replace
+  entry: check-copyright --verbose --replace
   language: python
   files: \.(py|c|h|cpp|hpp|ld|s|S)$
   require_serial: true
\ No newline at end of file
diff --git a/setup.py b/setup.py
index 97b5cc6..c5c01bb 100644
--- a/setup.py
+++ b/setup.py
@@ -33,5 +33,6 @@ setuptools.setup(
     url=URL,
     install_requires=REQUIRES,
     py_modules=['check_copyright'],
-    scripts=['check_copyright.py']
+    scripts=['check_copyright.py'],
+    entry_points={'console_scripts': ['check-copyright=check_copyright:main']},
 )
```

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget that in Python `\` is an escape character. For Windows paths, you'd need to double them up with a second `\`. Depending on if you're using Python 2 or Python 3, you can use the following approaches to make your file path OS agnostic.

### os.path.join()

Prior to Python 3.4, you would use `os.path.join()` to create an agnostic path. It is a little awkward to use however, since you need to issue a new call for each directory in your path. For example, if I want to have a path to the folder `source_code/my_clones/projA`, I would have to use the following code:

```
clone_path = os.path.join("source_code", "my_clones")
proj_path = os.path.join(clone_path, "projA")
```

As you can see, this is not particularly nice and is very cumbersome for large file paths.

### Pathlib

The Pathlib library was introduced in Python 3. Its handling of paths is much better. Simply specify the UNIX-style path and the library will handle the OS-specific path conversions for you. Taking a look at our previous example, `source_code/my_clones/projA`, you could write:

```
proj_path = Path("source_code/my_clones/projA")
```

Most file operations will handle the conversion for you when using pathlib.

Comment: Thanks, I know about that, but that is not a problem from my code. I just want to run my pre-commit script.
As you can see, `Executable C:Userstore.cachepre-commitrepoq2jv0lxhpy_env-python3.9Scriptspython.EXE not found` means the problem with running script by pre-commit or something another (for example, setup.py). So, I don't have any place, where I can change it :(

Comment: Also, that script worked on Windows before we move it to the separate repository for pre-commit